# How to retrieve audit records (Search-UnifiedAuditLog) from ExchangeOnline with C#

Tags: c#, powershell

***Background***:

Using the instructions given at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/18/access-exchange-online-by-powershell-in-c/ I can retrieve basic info from Exchange Online. However, when I try to retrieve audit records using Search-UnifiedAuditLog cmdlet, it returns nothing (*I can retrive the records using Powershell command line*).

**Question**:

How can I use Search-UnifiedAuditLog cmdlet from C#?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Just starting to look at this. Found generic Powershell command examples here: https://gist.github.com/miteshsureja/f9cbc2f09264a01277a6555a7425debc